# Is a block_device mapping a physical disk or a partition of the disk?

Tags: linux-kernel, hard-disk, block-device

In the ULK(Understanding Linux Kernel) book, the author says each block device has its own driver. The question is, does the block device here represent a physical disk or just a partition of the disk?

It's written in the book that struct block_device can be a partition or the disk(signified by "bd_contains" attribute). However, the struct gendisk can also represent a disk. I'm quite confused that is "the disk" these two structs refers to the same thing?

Comment: I am not familiar with the book, but a block device can represent an entire physical disk or a partition as well. If you go to /dev you will see that there is an entry for /dev/sdX which represents an entire physical disk as well as entries for /dev/sdXY which represent a partition of that disk

Comment: It has a driver. Own makes it sound like they all have a different one, and this is not true. All sata devices will share a driver, and all partitions will share a driver.

Comment: Each disk has a block device, each partition has a block device, each LVM logical disk has a block device...

Comment: Do you mean [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005658.do)?

Comment: Right @Schaller

Answer (score 2):

At the fundamental level, a block device represents a set of N blocks of data, with some fixed block size. The blocks are numbered consecutively 0 .. (N-1).

This could be a physical disk, a partition, a RAID array consisting of *multiple* physical disks, a LVM logical volume consisting of *parts of one or more disks*, or a virtual view of any of the above through an encryption layer.

A filesystem driver does not generally care about the physical details: it only deals with representing that range of blocks as a functional filesystem. The underlying driver(s) may translate the block numbers any way they deem necessary, as long as each block is uniquely addressable by its number.

- A partition driver just applies an offset to the block number and refers to the underlying whole-disk device.
- A LVM logical volume driver has a table of ranges of logical block numbers and corresponding (underlying device + offset) pairs.
- A RAID driver can have many underlying devices, and a request for a single block can map to several underlying blocks on different devices, for redundancy. A single read request can be split between multiple underlying devices that have identical content for performance, or recovered from other underlying devices if one of them has failed; a write request may need to be repeated on each underlying device (for RAID1) and/or have checksums calculated for it (for RAID5/6).
- A multipath driver has *several* underlying (path) devices all connecting to the *same* storage device at the far end of the paths. It does not change the block number, but may retry the same operation on multiple paths if necessary.
- A disk encryption driver may or may not map the block numbers (to obfuscate the real disk access patterns), but it will certainly modify the data passing through it: any blocks to be written are encrypted before passing the request on to the underlying device, and any data read from the underlying device is decrypted.

Since a block device has basically the same interface whether it's a physical disk, a partition, a LVM LV, a RAID device, or something else, all these mapping drivers are **stackable**: you can freely place these mapping layers on top of each other. Of course, not all combinations are guaranteed to be sensible, or even useful.

Comment: What you mentioned is quite right in the physical disk management.